# "x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1000000,) and (10000,)" for two different arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I am writing a program to graph bode plots of filter circuits but when I define two arrays of values to be plotted on two different graphs (one with 10,000 values and one with 1,000,000 values) it gives the error "x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1000000,) and (10000,)"
I am using numpy and matplotlib to do this. In a different program I was able to change the array using the code:
`t = np.arange(-4,4,.01)`
and then later redefine it as `t = np.arange(-7,5,.01)` without error, but that wont work here.
I have tried to define two different arrays but it still gives the same error. My code is as follow:

```
The program starts by importin code libraries that will be used later on

import numpy as np 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.integrate import quad

# Question 1

1a

The Frequency response H(w) is given by:

def H(w):
  out = 1/(1+((w)/wc))
  return out

1b

Freq1 = np.arange(0,10000,1)    #the frequency F is defined by this array from 0 to 10,000Hz with a step of 1
Fc = 2500     #this is the cut off frequency defined in the question
w1 = Freq1*2*np.pi     #this is the formula for converting the frequncy in hertz to radians per second
wc1 = Fc*2*np.pi     #this is the formula for converting the cut off frequncy in hertz to radians per second

The formula for the magnitude plot for this circuit is given by:

def H(Freq1):
  out = (1/(1+((w)/wc)**2))**0.5
  return out

The magnitude of the frequency responce is graphed bellow in red with the cut off frequency marked with the blue line when the magnitude is equal to 1/√2

plt.plot(Freq1,H(Freq1), color="red")    #this sets the parameters for the x and y axes and defines the colour of the line
plt.plot([0, 2500, 2500], [(1/2**0.5), (1/2**0.5), 0])
plt.ylabel('H(F)', color="blue")   #this is the label and label colour of the y axis
plt.xlabel('F',horizontalalignment='right', color="blue")    #this is the label and label colour of the x axis
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,1.1,0.1), color="green")   #here the markings for the y axis are defined
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,10000,1000), color="green")    #here the markings for the x axis are defined
plt.grid(True)      #this creates a grid on the plot

The formula for the phase plot for this circuit is given by:

def P(F):
  out = -np.arctan(w/wc)
  return out


Graphed below is the phase plot of the circuit, the x axis in logarithmic and the y is linear

F=np.arange(0,1000000,1)
plt.plot(F,P(F), color="red")    #this sets the parameters for the x and y axes and defines the colour of the line
plt.ylabel('P(F)', color="blue")   #this is the label and label colour of the y axis
plt.xlabel('F',horizontalalignment='right', color="blue")    #this is the label and label colour of the x axis
plt.xscale("log")   #this sets the scale on the x axis to be logarithmic, making it easier to identify trends in the graph
plt.grid(True)      #this creates a grid on the plot
```

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: your function `P(F)` is not using `F`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . It is important to have some care about what you share, so that the SO community can try to help. In your code, there is text that is not commented out, it imports something from scipy which is not used, and does not define ```w```, although it is used.

Comment: Just a guess (I could not run your code), you define a function ```P(F)``` and ```H(Freq1)```, but you don't actually use ```F```  or ```Freq1``` inside the functions. They use ```w``` instead. The code you shared does not define ```w```, but maybe it is an array of shape (10000,) (?).